# How to wrap parameter in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

What is the right setting for wrapping parameter in VS Code on the same level?

This is what I have:

```
constructor(private stateParams: angular.ui.IStateParamsService, 
  private $interval: angular.IIntervalService) {
```

This is what I would like to:

```
constructor(private stateParams: angular.ui.IStateParamsService, 
            private $interval: angular.IIntervalService) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

```
"editor.wrappingIndent": "same"
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Prettier-Code Formatter (esbenp.prettier-vscode) extention.
That will ease your work. Settings and any further info is provided in plugin documentation.